# no puede importar el nombre 'DATA_PATH' mientras lo crea con export

Tags: python, python-3.x, rutas

Tengo un archivo `config.py` que parece importar una variable `DATA_PATH`:

`config.py`

```
import logging
import os

from config import DATA_PATH, formatter, logger


filepath = os.path.join(DATA_PATH, "scrap.log")
fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(filepath)
fileHandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger.addHandler(fileHandler)
```

Es extrano que llama a config que es el su nombre mismo:

```
antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/jom (master) $ python3 scraper/scraper_run.py 
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.8) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper/scraper_run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scraper_sephora_USA import sephora_usa
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/jom/scraper/scraper_sephora_USA.py", line 3, in <module>
    from config import logger
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/jom/scraper/config.py", line 4, in <module>
    from config import DATA_PATH, formatter, logger
ImportError: cannot import name 'DATA_PATH'
```

Entonces intenté crear el path hasta el folder `data` pero no parece ser sufficiente:

```
antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/jom (master) $ pwd
/home/ubuntu/environment/jom
                                                            
antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/jom (master) $ export DATA_PATH=/home/ubuntu/environment/jom/data

antoine.cop1@protonmail.com:~/environment/jom (master) $ python3 scraper/scraper_run.py 
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.26.8) or chardet (3.0.4) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper/scraper_run.py", line 3, in <module>
    from scraper_sephora_USA import sephora_usa
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/jom/scraper/scraper_sephora_USA.py", line 3, in <module>
    from config import logger
  File "/home/ubuntu/environment/jom/scraper/config.py", line 4, in <module>
    from config import DATA_PATH, formatter, logger
ImportError: cannot import name 'DATA_PATH'
```

Comment: ¿Tienes un archivo llamado "config.py" dentro del cual haces "from config import xxx"? ¿Que se supone que hace?

Comment: Si @CandidMoe es muy extanño, no escribí este archivo

Comment: ¿Cómo se llamaba originalmente ese archivo?

Comment: Es su nombre mismo @CandidMoe lo recibí como tal